# game of craps dice roll stuck in infinte loop

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a program for a game of craps where the user enters a bet amount and 2 six sided dice are rolled if 7 or 11 are rolled they win. if 2,3 or 12 roll they lose, if any other number is rolled it displays the number as a point.It will keep rolling the dice until either 7 or the point is rolled, if 7 is rolled they lose, else they win. For some reason is rolls the dice rolls more then once when rolling the dice to see if they won or lost. I am not sure how to fix this
any help would be appericated

```
 static int RollDice()
    {

        int roll;


        Random random = new Random();
        int die1 = 0;
        int die2 = 0;

        die1 = random.Next(1,6);

        die2 = random.Next(1,6);

        roll = die1 + die2;
        Console.WriteLine($"You rolled {die1} + {die2} = {roll}");
        return roll;

    }

    static void processCraps()
    {

        string gameStatus;
        double betAmount;
        double netWinning = 0;
        int point;


            do
            { 
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount to bet");
                betAmount = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());



                if (RollDice() == 2 || RollDice() == 3 || RollDice() == 12)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"You lost {betAmount}");
                    netWinning = netWinning - betAmount;

                }
                else if (RollDice() == 7 || RollDice() == 11)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"You won {betAmount}");
                    netWinning = netWinning + betAmount;
                }
                else if (RollDice() != 2 || RollDice() != 3 || RollDice() != 12 || RollDice() != 7 || RollDice() != 11)
                {

                    point = RollDice();
                    Console.WriteLine($"Point is {point}");
                   for(int rollCount =0; rollCount <= point; RollDice() )
                {
                   if(RollDice() == 7)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"You lost {betAmount}");
                        netWinning = netWinning - betAmount;
                    }
                   else if(RollDice() == point)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"You won {betAmount}");
                        netWinning = netWinning + betAmount;
                    }

                }

                }

                Console.WriteLine("Do you want to play again (y/n)");
                gameStatus = Console.ReadLine();



            } while (gameStatus == "y") ;
            Console.WriteLine($"Your net winning is {netWinning}");

        }
```

Comment: You are calling `RollDice` too many times. Call it once after they enter the bet amount and store the result in a variable. Then use that variable to check the value that was rolled - see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling RollDice too many times. Call it once after they enter the bet amount and store the result in a variable. Then use that variable to check the value that was rolled e.g.

```
static void processCraps()
{
    string gameStatus;
    double betAmount;
    double netWinning = 0;
    int point;


    do
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount to bet");
        betAmount = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        var diceRoll = RollDice();
        if (diceRoll == 2 || diceRoll == 3 || diceRoll == 12)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"You lost {betAmount}");
            netWinning = netWinning - betAmount;
        }
        ... // repeat for the other rolls
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `if` statements. Here for example

```
if (RollDice() == 2 || RollDice() == 3 || RollDice() == 12)
```

Every one of those `RollDice()` is a call to the function. If you only want to roll once, call the function once and assign the result to a variable and check it, thusly:

```
int roll = RollDice();
if (roll == 2 || roll == 3 || roll == 12)
```